# springboot postgress connection failed

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

i m using my postgress db for a microservice using org.postgress and jpa dependency , i have this error :APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

i tried many solution but none working , my application.properties are in the folder src/main with this configuration :
# Database configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/musicDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

any solution??

Comment: application.properties should be in src/main/resources folder. It's the default place.